# finding a coprime number of a general magnitude

Tags: algorithm, primes, modulo

I have an arbitrary number `x`.  I would like to compute a number that is coprime to `x` that's close(ish) to the square root of `x`.  I don't need to find them all, and factoring `x` is expensive.  I just need one number.

Constant time, preferably.

Comment: Pick a prime, that doesn't divide x, close(ish) to root x?

Comment: computing primes is expensive...

Comment: ... and there's a lot of them... unless they are "special" primes.  Mersenne primes are too sparse, there are something like log(x) of them less than x.  However, if there were a class of primes for which there were root(x) of them less than x, nicely distributed, closed-form to find, that would be ideal.  I was hoping for a solution like this... Euclidean algo is log(x), and I dunno about the distribution of coprimes for an arbitrary number, but the distribution of primes is such that finding a prime near root(x) is expected at >> log(x)... log(x)^2 I think.

Comment: If your numbers are of moderate size (eg 32 bits) then you could have a table of primes in your program; the cost of computing this is then at compile time

Comment: duplicate from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430742/finding-a-coprime-of-a-general-magnitude . Brute force finding iteratively a coprime number to x is O(ln(x)), but it can be done in O(ln(ln(x)))

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the GCD with the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) quite efficiently, so if you just try the numbers close to the square root you should find a candidate very quickly.

You are unlikely to get a whole string of numbers that have common factors because if you find a common prime p, the next time you can get hit by the same prime is p later.